# Как сделать фильтрацию?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

https://jsbin.com/jigapuvupu/edit?html,js,output - Есть json квартир, при нажатии на номер этажа должны отобразиться те квартиры которые есть на этом этаже. Как сделать фильтрацию json таким образом чтобы исключить отсутствующие квартиры и получить те которые есть на этом этаже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логику с нажималкой придумайте свою, но вот вам функция для фильрации

```
const filterByFoor = (quaters, floor) => quaters.filter(qarter => qarter.floor.includes(floor));

const quaters = [
  {
    id: 1,
    room: 1,
    floor: [1, 3, 4]
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    room: 1,
    floor: [1, 2, 3]
  },

  {
    id: 3,
    room: 2,
    floor: [3, 4]
  },

  {
    id: 4,
    room: 2,
    floor: [3, 4]
  }
]


console.log(filterByFoor(quaters, 2));
console.log(filterByFoor(quaters, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

входной массив только не логичный) ну или я не понял чего-то.

Работает так: вы вводите этаж (например 1) и получите `quaters.room` если в `quaters.floor` содержится вводимое число.

```js
let quaters = [
  {
    id: 1,
    room: 1,
    floor: [1, 3, 4]
  },
  
  {
    id: 2,
    room: 1,
    floor: [1, 2, 3]
  },
  
  {
    id: 3,
    room: 2,
    floor: [3, 4]
  },
  
  {
    id: 4,
    room: 2,
    floor: [3, 4]
  }
];

$("#inp").on('input', function(){
 $("#result").empty();
  let currentFloor = $(this).val();
  quaters.forEach(function(e){
    e.floor.forEach(item => {
       //console.log(item);
       if(currentFloor == item) $("#result").append("<p>"+ e.room +"</p>");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inp">
<div id="result"></div>
```